# How can I make rules dinamically? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rules

My case like thi:

My view like this :

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
    <input type="hidden" name="photo-{{$i}}">
    ...
@endfor
```

My rules like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            'photo-0'=> 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

My controller like this :

```
public function store(CreateProductRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

From the code,  name photo-0 is required

But I want to make it dinamically

So not photo-0 is required, but at least one photo is required

For example photo-0 has no value, but photo-3 has value, then it can run statement in store method

How can I do it?

**Update** :

If I analyze it, it seems there will be a loop inside the return array (in rules method). Is that possible?

I try like this :

```
public function rules()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $photo[] = 'photo-'.$i;
    }
    return [
        ...
        'photo'=> 'required'
    ];
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below view and controller code and it works so you may adjust your view code according to this

view

```
<body>

<form method="post" action="/testingFiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="file" name="filesUpload[]">
    <input type="file" name="filesUpload[]">
    <input type="file" name="filesUpload[]">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

@if (count($errors))
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'filesUpload' => 'required'
        ]);
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

Comment: Your answer does not fit my case. I use the input type hidden. Not the input file type. In my case, the photo is not a file, but it is worth a string